# Identity url and reply url - Single sign on

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am getting the below error in **Single sign-on**.

> **AADSTS50011**: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application:
> 'http://******/60ff6f*****4-437a-430e-a63a-*****'.

Anyone know where to check the `reply-url` and `identity-url` in azure app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using the SAML as the single sign-on mode, if so, just navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `Enterprise applications` -> `All applications` -> filter with `All applications` and search for your app, then in your app -> `Single sign-on`, the `Reply URL` and `Identifier` are the `reply-url` and `identity-url` you want to check.

[image]